# Using Julia abstract types in other modules

Tags: types, scope, julia

I am trying to work with abstract types in Julia, and am encountering some problems which I can't seem to figure out on my own.

Let's say I have 2 Julia modules and a script (or REPL) in different files such that they look like so:

```
------------------------------------- File 1

module Mod1
  export AbstractThing

  abstract type AbstractThing end

end

------------------------------------- File 2

module Mod2 
  export Thing
  
  include("path/to/File1")
  using Mod1
  
  struct Thing <: AbstractThing
    ...
  end

  function f1()
    v :: Vector{AbstractThing} = []
    push!(v,Thing())
  end
end

------------------------------------- File 3

  include("path/to/File1")
  using Mod1

  include("path/to/File2")
  using Mod2

  function f2()
    v :: Vector{AbstractThing} = []
    push!(v,Thing())
  end

  function f3()
    v :: Vector{Main.Mod2.Mod1.AbstractThing} = []
    push!(v,Thing())
  end
```

What I would like is for `f2()` to work, but for some reason it does not. When executed from the REPL, it returns the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Thing to an object of type AbstractThing
```

It has something to do with scope, because both `f1()` and `f3()` work, but I can't really figure out what is wrong or what I should do to fix it.

Can someone explain how type scope works in this sort of context and how to fix it? Why is Julia seeing `Main.Mod2.Mod1.AbstractThing` and `Main.Mod1.AbstractThing` as separate types? How can I fix this?

---

Update:

After some more testing, I think the problem is that the Julia interpreter does not recognise that Mod1 and Mod2.Mod1 are actually the same module. Here are some of the outputs I got from the REPL that make me think this:

```
julia> AbstractThing === Mod1.AbstractThing
true

julia> AbstractThing === Mod2.Mod1.AbstractThing
false

julia> Thing <: Mod1.AbstractThing
false

julia> Thing <: Mod2.Mod1.AbstractThing
true
```

So it is definitely looking at the two definitions of `AbstractThing` and considering them as different. How can this be solved I do not know, but restructuring my files is not an option I am afraid. I want different people to be able to implement their own `Thing` struct, based on a template that is then recognised in `Mod1`.

Could making `Mod1` an actual package (and not simply a local module) work?

Comment: You'll need to restructure your code so it doesn't `include` the same file twice.

Comment: Ok. Right now I have to include the files in order to be able to use the modules (otherwise Julia cannot find them). If I make an actual package for ```Mod1``` I won't have to include it, right? So that could be a solution.

Comment: @JordiManyerFuertes: even for a pkg if you split your code in multiple files (as it is usual) you need to include the files, but see my answer below..

Comment: @JordiManyerFuertes: even for a pkg if you split your code in multiple files (as it is usual) you need to include the files, but see my answer below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @pfitzseb commented to you, you need to restructure your code in order to avoid including a file twice.
The following is an example that works. See also my [tutorial on packages or modules](https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/11-developing-julia-packages) (also available as YouTube [video](https://youtu.be/_qTLSrk1ICA)):

```
------------------------------------- file1.jl:
module Mod1
  export AbstractThing

  abstract type AbstractThing end

end
------------------------------------- file2.jl:
module Mod2 
  export Thing, f1
  using ..Mod1 # You need to "go up" one level to main and then "go down" one level to Mod1
  
  struct Thing <: AbstractThing
    
  end

  function f1()
    v :: Vector{AbstractThing} = []
    push!(v,Thing())
  end
end
------------------------------------- file3.jl:
include("file1.jl") # Do all the "includes" at the beginning of your project..
include("file2.jl")
using .Mod1 # Here you are in Main, you need to go down one level to Mod1..
using .Mod2 # Same here to Mod2

function f2()
  v :: Vector{AbstractThing} = []
  push!(v,Thing())
end

function f3()
  v :: Vector{Main.Mod2.Mod1.AbstractThing} = []
  push!(v,Thing())
end

f1()
f2()
f3()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I'll be definitely be checking your guide.

Comment: The main thing to understand is that in Julia the parsing of the file and the compilation happen at two different moments.. So while a traditional compiled language would not like the kind or code organisation above, because when Mod2 is compiled the compiler doesn't yet have Mod1 on scope, Julia just parses the code and it is fine with it, and compilation happens in JIT only later at calling time, and at that time Mod1 is on scope so all works nicely :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `AbstractThing` to be able to extend it. Try adding a line

```
import Mod1.AbstractThing
```

just after the line with `using Mod1` in your definition of `Mod2`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've tested it and does not work. I think the problem is rather in the direction I've added in my post update. The Julia interpreter is just considering the two instances of ```Mod1``` to be different and thus does not know how to convert from one to the other.